# How can i get the content of a subview in a UIScrollview in a specific order according to a tag or something similar?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, subview

How can i get the the `label.text` inside of the view added to the `UIScrollview` but in a specific order, each label has a consecutive tag 1,2,3,4,5, this is important because each one need to be save in a array in that order.

The problem is, that when a use the search, it sends the labels in a different order, how can i control this?

my code to search is:

```
for (UIView *addedView in [self.scrollView subviews]){
    for (UIView *sub in [addedView subviews])
    {
        if([sub isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            UILabel *myLabel = (UILabel *)sub;
            [array addObject:mylabel.text];
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your scrollview can contain many subviews all having tag as 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1 ;i <= [self.scrollView.subviews count] ;i++){
        UIView *myView = (UIView *) [addedView viewWithTag:i];

           if(myView && [myView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
           UILabel *label = (UILabel *)myView;
            [array addObject:label.text]; );
        }
    }
```

Comment: this will take all the subviews, but what will happen if the tag=2 doesnt exist for a label? i guess that the application will crash in runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you access your views based on the tag they carry?

```
UIView* view = [self.scrollView viewWithTag:tag];
```

if you iterate over all the tags you have defined, this will allow you to control the order in which you process the views. Otherwise, I suspect that `subviews` will mirror the subviews stack-up order. You could try with:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
    UIView* view = [self.scrollView viewWithTag:i];
    ...
}
```

Even better you could also assign the label's tag and then use:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
    UIView* view = [self.scrollView viewWithTag:i];
    UILabel* myLabel = (UILabel*)[view viewWithTag:kLabelTag];
    ...
}
```